# $\rm{NTIME}(n)\neq \rm{P}$ using padding argument

Tags: solution-verification, computational-complexity

Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $\rm{NTIME}(n)=\rm{P}$. Let
$L\in\rm{NTIME}(n^{2})$ and let a NDTM $M$ that decides $L$ in $cn^2$ time,
for some constant $c$. Consider now the language
\begin{equation*}
    L_{\rm{pad}}=\left\{\langle x,1^{|x|^{2}}\rangle\colon x\in L\right\}.
\end{equation*}
$L_{\rm{pad}}\in\rm{NTIME}(n)$. To show this we construct the
following NDTM $M'$: given an input $y$, check if there is a string $x$
such that $y=\langle x,1^{|x|^{2}}\rangle$. If there isn't some, output
$0$. If yes, then simulate $M$
with input $x$ for $c|x|^{2}$ steps and output its answer.

Obviously, $M'$ decides $L_{\rm{pad}}$ and $M'$ runs in linear time.
Indeed, for an input $y$, $M'$ will simulate $M$ for at most $c|y|$ steps since if $y=\langle x,1^{|x|^{2}}\rangle$ then $|y|=|x|+|x|^{2}$ and so $c|x|^2\leq c|y|$.

Thus, we have proved that $L_{\rm{pad}}\in\rm{NTIME}(n)=\rm{P}$. Now, clearly
the function $x\mapsto \langle x,1^{|x|^{2}}\rangle$ is a polynomial
time reduction from $L$ to $L_{\rm{pad}}$ and since $L_{\rm{pad}}\in \rm{P}$ we have
also that $L\in \rm{P}$. Hence, $\rm{NTIME}(n^{2})\subseteq \rm{P}=\rm{NTIME}(n)$,
which is a contradiction since from the Nondeterministic Time Hierarchy Theorem we have that
$\rm{NTIME}(n)\subsetneq \rm{NTIME}(n^2)$.

---

My questions are the following:

- Is the computation of the running time of $M'$ correct?
- Is the final argument correct? It seems correct to me!